# In an FTP server, why should server open a port and not the client?

Tags: sockets, ftp

When a client wants to download something from an FTP server, the server opens a port and gives it to the client to connect with the server. My question is, why doesn't the client itself do that?
(Actually in this question we are talking about a client and server both in local host)

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can't delete it because someone answered it. what should I do to compensate the score? I can't ask any question because 3 of my questions have negative scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually FTP has an `active` and a `passive` mode. In `active` mode the client opens up a port `m` and the server connects to that port. Many clients are behind a firewall though and can't accept incoming connections and so the process reverses.

You can read more about FTP and its modes on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Communication_and_data_transfer).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Rezart Qelibari, in this case because the client (me) is behind a firewall and is unable to accept incoming TCP connections, passive mode may be used. In this mode, the client uses the control connection to send a PASV command to the server and then receives a server IP address and server port number from the server.